# How many colonies (populated solar systems) in the Radch Universe?

Tags: space-colonization, ann-leckie, imperial-radch

If there is no exact number, what is your proposed approximate number? What is your rationale for choosing this number?

Comment: A lot? Also are you asking only about systems belonging to humans? There are Presgers and others so human expansion wasn't unlimited. Still there may be thousands of worlds, even in Radch alone.